# php equivalent of mysql "IN" operator?

Tags: php, operators

I haven't coded in PHP in awhile and I'm not having luck with Googleing this basic question.

If I want to do something like:

```
if ($x == $a || $x == $b || $x == $foo || $x == $bar) { //whatever
```

What is a nice way to write it?  I'm thinking something like SQL's IN operator:

```
if ($x IN ($a, $b, $foo, $bar)) { //whatever
```

Is there a way to simplify the code without using an array?

Comment: Why do you say not to use an array?

Comment: @alexanderbird because I know how to do it with in_array... i wanted to know if there was a more... direct way.  I guess there isn't

Comment: wow, people are harsh tonight.  My Q is -3, the answers have negs... lol.  I think it was a valid question and thanks for the answers.

Comment: Yeah, tough night I guess I'll go to bed.

Comment: Probably delete to save a little.

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

However, it's worth noting that you're sort of conflating two types of languages; PHP is a scripting language, SQL is a query language. They serve two very different purposes and do very different things behind the scenes, so it's an important distinction.

[edit: Without using an array? Probably not, no; you're throwing out the construct that is specifically useful in this instance]